# How can i directly use a foreign key in hibernate without a object for it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin

Spring JPA Question:

We load quite a bit of data form a pretty slow service. Now each dto we load from the service has a foreign key to a table containing data. We don't need the data right away, just the key and we don't want to find the item containing the key each time, because we would need to put a repository into our mapper, which would make everything even slower. Is it possible to tell Hibernate just to reference the table without needing a object/`@ManyToOne`? Then we could just save the entity from our mapper right away without needing a custom mapping for the key.

So maybe something like:

```
@ForeignKey(tableName="itemTemperature", referencedColumnName="id")
var itemTemperatureId: Int = 0
```

Or does this work too:

```
var item = Item().apply {
    itemTemperature = ItemTemperature().apply { id = keyFormService }
}
itemRepository.save(item)
```

Comment: I think i found a post that solved your problem - [spring-data-jpa-get-entity-foreign-key-without-causing-the-dependent-entity-lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105036/spring-data-jpa-get-entity-foreign-key-without-causing-the-dependent-entity-lazy)

Comment: Not quite. I need to save a Entity to the database, so i'll need a proper object with `@ManyToOne`, but i just want to store the id with a foreign key like it is on the db^^